# Problem using a TV monitor as second monitor with Delphi code

Tags: delphi

I made an application that opens a window that I can toggle between two monitors with the following code.

```
const monitorNo : integer = 0;
var DPI : integer;
procedure TmainForm.SBtoggle(Sender: TObject);
begin
    monitorNo := (monitorNo +1 ) mod screen.MonitorCount;
    MakeFullyVisible(screen.Monitors[monitorNo]);

    // returns DPI = 0 for TV monitor
    // GetDpiForMonitor(mainForm.Monitor.Handle,MDT_RAW_DPI ,UINT(DPI),UINT(DPI));
end;
```

The app's window is always maximized.

I run the app with two monitors and works right, even the monitors have different DPI and Size.

I tried to run it with a TV monitor and a PC monitor but works ok only when the window is in `normal` mode.

When it is `maximized` appears (partially) only the caption bar of the window, the client area is transparent at all.

Have you any suggestions ?

PS. DPI awareness: `per monitor v2`  or `Unaware`

Comment: You don't check if GetDpiForMonitor fails - it could be returning E_INVALIDARG instead of S_OK.

Comment: indeed GetDpiForMonitor returns E_Invalidarg but forget it. The problem is that nothing is displayed in the client area of ​​the window by running MakeFullyVisible

Comment: [Code formatting shouldn't be used for emphasis on regular words.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/254995/3964075)

Comment: Microsoft's documentation says not to use GetDpiForMonitor() when using per-monitor DPI awareness, use GetDpiForWindow() instead.

Comment: @RemyLebeau, yes I know it. I have tried unaware mode and GetDpiForMonitor() with the same results. But this problem is not too severe. My real problem is that nothing is displayed in the client area of ​​the window (only at the TV monitor) by running MakeFullyVisible